# Unset specific array value equal to $_GET

Tags: php, arrays, session, get

I am making a shopping cart system using sessions. I need a way do unset 1/all values in array which is equal to the value of $_GET. How can this be done?

I've tried using the unset() function, but i dont know how to format it when using the $_GET value. All the tutorials i've seen, only shows how to unset something that is specified directly in the script...

EDIT: This is what i get, when i `var_dump` my session:
`array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(13) { 
        [0]=> NULL 
        [1]=> string(1) "1" 
        [2]=> string(1) "3" 
        [3]=> string(1) "2" 
        [4]=> string(1) "2" 
        [5]=> string(1) "3" 
        [6]=> string(1) "1" 
        [7]=> string(1) "3" 
        [8]=> string(1) "2" 
        [9]=> string(1) "1" 
        [10]=> string(1) "3" 
        [11]=> string(1) "3" 
        [12]=> string(1) "3" 
    } 
}`

I am adding item to the cart with this line of code:

```
array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $_GET['item']);
```

Where $_SESSION['cart'] is the shopping cart and $_GET['item'] is the item id that is added

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Can you show us a structure of the shopping cart please?

Comment: Just added the structure to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple replace its value

```
$_SESSION['cart']=array_diff($_SESSION['cart'], $_GET['item']);
```

**EDIT**

```
Make sure $_SESSION['cart'], $_GET['item'] have same structure
```

**UPDATE**

```
if(is_array($_GET['item']) && is_array($_SESSION['cart']))
{
foreach($_GET['item'] as $value)
{
  foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key=>$val)
  {
    if($value == $val)
    {
    unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
    break;
    }
  }
}
} else { echo "error";}
```

Comment: wait wait argument #2 is not array.. means your $_GET['item'] is not array

Comment: Okay I just got it to work. Is it possible to only delete 1 of the values equal to $_GET?

Comment: Ofcourse array_diff() outputs the difference between two arrays

Comment: Then how to i delete just 1 of them?

Comment: I dont understand what you are asking.. it delets everything that $_GET have.. if GET have only 1 value then it will be removed..

Comment: if we say that $_get is equal to 1, and $cart contains 3 one's. How do i delete just 1 of the one's so i end up with 2 one's??

Comment: No.. for that you will have to loop through second array and unset() unwanted element

Comment: Could you please provide a code for this? it would be very appreciated :)

Comment: Code under UPDATE is what you wanted.. it is not tested .. check and respond

Comment: I am getting "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" on the line with "foreach($_session..."

Comment: this is because either session or get is not array.. my code is correct

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to fix it? I know that the session is an array, but the post might just be a string. Can i convert it into an array somehow? :)

Comment: nevermind, i just made it work by using the str_split() function on the GET :) Thank you for all your help. You really helped me out alot :D

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your shopping cart has the following structure, you can simply use this to unset it

```
$cart = array("cat1" => array("product_1", "product_2"), "cat2" => array("product_3", "product_4"));
unset($cart[$_GET['category']]);
```

Comment: Can you show us the structure of your shopping cart please? some code?

Comment: Just added some samples of the way i add items to the cart